# Intent not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-intent, request, http-post

I have created code. Intent is not opening,in both conditions the default one executes.i have tried from if else statement to but got the same result.some one can check my code and do some help. Thanks in advance.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        //If we are getting success from server
        switch (response) {
            case "success": {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `break;` to the end of your `case "success":` block.

If you do not have some sort of `break` or `return` at the end of your switch case, it will simply continue on to the next case. That's why you see the `Toast` no matter what.

Official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Then the string must not be `"success"`. Can you use the debugger to see its value?

Comment: i have done every thing,changed string into integers 1 and 0 but same results come.the conditional structure is being ignored everytime,default and else statement is running.even success gets print on toast in default case.but why not in condition.